# Bash -- Using a character-based graphical utility to store output

Tags: bash, scripting, graphical-user-interface, modem

I'm using bash to script a remote dialing program in an Ubuntu(14.04) server and I am having some significant trouble trying to read the output from it. I would like the program to execute as I would normally have it and then I have the timeout command kill it, like so:

```
#!/usr/bash 

echo "begin"

timeout 60s minicom Cisco -d Boston >> log.txt
```

I am able to run the above command alone on the console without any sort of hiccups however when I run it through bash nothing really seems to happen, it goes through the timeout, but I just end up with these characters in log.txt:

```
^[[0m^O
```

I'm a bit green when it comes to scripting in bash; is there perhaps a rule about appending output from a graphical utility to output? I'm really quite confused as to why it is doing this.

Answer (score 3):

From `man minicom`

```
   -C, --capturefile=FILE
        filename.  Open capture file at startup.
```

So, simply do this:

```
#!/usr/bash 

echo "begin"

timeout 60s minicom Cisco -d Boston -C log.txt
```

Comment: When testing this solution I found that nothing was written to the specified logfile.

Comment: Shouldn't you be echoing "begin" to `Cisco` ? Like so: `echo "begin" >> Cisco`